# What is a mashal?

Tags: allegory-mashal

I just watched an Italian video and discovered the existence of "mashal" (I hope the spelling is correct), but I don't understand if it's a joke or a fake joke... Thanks.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't think it's off-topic; *mashal* is a Jewish concept and asking what it is seems on-topic.  However, the question is unclear; I don't know what "joke or fake joke" means.  Iscritto Iscritti, if you [edit] to clarify your question, the community will review it for possible reopening.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, I agree with the closure reason, FWIW. _Mashal_ is not particularly a Judaism concept, and the question gives no indication that the word was used in a Judaism context.

Comment: @msh210 oh, ok -- the only context where I've ever heard it has been in Jewish text study, so I thought it was more specialized.

Answer (score 4):

I would generally translate *mashal* as [parable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable). To quote from Wikipedia:

> A parable is a succinct, didactic story, in prose or verse that illustrates one or more instructive lessons or principles.

Answer (score 2):

The translation of the word **מָשָל** (mashal) depends on the context. 
Sometimes, it may be better translated into "an example" (for example = למשל) and sometimes it may translated as proverb or allegory. Again, It depends on the context. In Spair Hebrew dictionary there are 5(!) definitions for this word.